# With node express passport and LocalStrategy, How to default req.user when not authenticated?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I would like to pass some default data into my application using the `req.user` object that Passport LocalStrategy sets for me when a user logs.  That is, `passport.deserializeUser` gets passed a function that creates the attributes on my `req.user` object that gets returned to the browser.

I would like to set something different to that req.user, but only when the user is not authenticated.  How can I do that?

Comment: Post your code, Are you using failure URL ?

Comment: I don't know what failureUrl is so no, I don't think I'm using it. Regarding my code, there is nothing special about it. It's just passport with LocalStrategy exactly like the web site example that returns req.user

Comment: `app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' })); ` Write your function on failure route. [Redirects](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/#redirects)